# Button label on top of button using before selector not working

Tags: html, css, hover

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/magnix2k/6qkb2dmL/8/)**

When the button hovers the label "Sign Up!" disappears. I put `color: rgba(32,32,32,1);` to the selected element `.button` and to the `::before` selector (in case if the `.button` didn't work) to display the label on top of the button.

On the selected element `.button` I even put `z-index: 9999` and that didn't help either.

The only thing I notice the `background-color: rgba(255,187,17,1);` of the button works inside the `::before`. Why is the `color:` not working?

Thanks for your wisdom!

HTML

```
<div class="button">SIGN UP!</div>
```

CSS

```
.button {
    position: relative;
    color: rgba(32, 32, 32, 1);
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    margin: auto 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.button::before {
    color: rgba(32, 32, 32, 1);
    background-color: rgba(255, 187, 17, 1);
    border-radius: 8px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1; 
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.button:hover::before {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
}

.button::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    border: 1px solid #959595;
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
}

.button:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

Comment: z-index:-1 on the before element and z-index:0 on the button element

Comment: That works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your .button::before doesn't have any content. So the color is applied to the empty string. If you type in something in there that is going to be colored (https://jsfiddle.net/Lwj24gbp/3/)

```
.button::before {
    color: rgba(32, 32, 32, 1);
    content: ''; // Try adding some content here. It's going to be the rgba(32, 32, 32, 1) color
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't use `content: ''` because it will transition the label when the button hovers. The label needs to stay and not move.